# Codeigniter helper extending

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller/test.php

```
<?php
class Test extends Controller {
    function __construct() {

    }
    function show_date(){
        $this->load->helper('date');
        echo "current date in mysql format" . date_mysql();
    }
}
?>
```

application/helpers

```
<?php
function date_mysql(){
    if(!time){
        $time = time();
     }
     return date('Y-m-d H-i-s', $time);
}
?>
```

and im gettting error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object in
>   F:\Xampp\htdocs\ci_series\application\controllers\test.php on line 12

what can i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the parent to your __constructor function. Like this;

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

This question should help you;

[PHP Codeigniter - parent::__construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809517/php-codeigniter-parent-construct)

Comment: Thanks bro, but can u tell me, why this is needed here??

Comment: Apologise. I have updated my answer, with a URL which will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CI_Controller** this

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
```

I have just tested both on CI 2.x and on CI 3

**application/controllers/Test.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function show_date() {

        $this->load->helper('date');
        echo "current date in mysql format " . date_mysql();

    }

}
?>
```

**application/helpers/date_helper.php**

```
<?php
function date_mysql( $time = false ){

    return date('Y-m-d H-i-s', !$time ? time() : $time);

}
?>
```

What is helpfull?