# constructor - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

Can anyone tell me why is the constructor in controller code using parent::__construct ? I only know it is because this is to use the method in parent class which is  within CI_Controller.
If so, why is the constructor in model code not using parent::__construct?

```
class News extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
} 



class News_model extends CI_Model
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}
```

Comment: You need to call the constructor of the parent, because if you don't you can't use any of the properties like 'load'.

Comment: [FOR you information we can use ` parent::__construct` in model file too](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html?highlight=models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - The reason this line is necessary is because your **local constructor will be overriding the one in the parent controller class** so we need to manually call it.
> - Constructors are **useful if you need to set some default values**, or run a default process when your class is instantiated. Constructors can't return a value, but they can do some default work.

Read [Codeigniter Constructors](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors)

And Possible Duplicate of [PHP Codeigniter - parent::__construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809517/php-codeigniter-parent-construct)

**Example**

```
public function  __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('My_model');
    $this->load->library('cart');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include `parent::__construct();` to  include the extended class 
default constructor initialization of codeigniter if you don't include that you will override the parent class constructor. `function __construct()` always run when the class is instantiate, so if you want to load some libraries or initialize some value its good to put it there.