# Fatal error: Call to a member function library() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using `CodeIgniter` and when my code try to load

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Appointments::$load
>
> Filename: controllers/appointments.php
>
> Line Number: 7

I don't know how to fix this? What's the cause? I should provide something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can tell that this error is inside constructor.

Constructor should be like this,

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();// you have missed this line.
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```

Comment: nice catch, I would recommend reading this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809517/php-codeigniter-parent-construct