# What does "parent::__construct($model)" functionality?

Tags: php, laravel

I am studying a friend's project and I'm confused why he use `parent::__construct($model)` and `$this->model = $model` at the same time in **CategoryRepository.php**. Could someone help me understand what's the difference of the two please?

I've already been to these links [PHP Codeigniter - parent::__construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809517/php-codeigniter-parent-construct),
[A __construct on an Eloquent Laravel Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502922/a-construct-on-an-eloquent-laravel-model) but I want a more specific answer correlating to the code below.

---

Here is the code of **CategoryRepository.php**

```
class CategoryRepository extends BaseRepository implements CategoryContract
{
    public function __construct(Category $model)
    {
        parent::__construct($model);
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

**BaseRepository.php**

```
class BaseRepository implements BaseContract
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the code given there is no difference. `$this->model = $model;` is not required in `CategoryRepository` because it is being set in `BaseRepository` but it won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent` is a PHP keyword use call a property or method of a *parent* class.

So `parent::__construct($model)` will call the `__construct` method of the parent class (`BaseRepository`, here).

When extending a class, it is sometimes necessary to call the parent constructor, when, let's say, the parent class is also initialising some properties needed. Instead of initialising them in child class constructor, you just need to call the parent class constructor and pass to it the necessary arguments.

Now in your question, `this->model = $model;` is not really needed in the child constructor (constructor in `CategoryRepository`) because it will be already initialized when call to `parent::__construct($model)` and will be accessible in the child class.

`this->model = $model;` will actually be necessary if `$model` in `BaseRepository` was a `private` property. Then it will not be available in the child class `CategoryRepository` even if the parent constructor was called.